# Why is this html pattern of input type="checkbox" lable for breaking the ngx-bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: html, css, angular

icheck-bootstrap is a pure css checkboxes and radio buttons for Twitter bootstrap.  This implies it will work with any of the frontend libraries.  At least that's the way I figured it... And indeed, his use from the readme of his github page for the library :[Link to icheck-bootstrap demo with docs](https://github.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap) Does work it just has a side effect that I can live with.

In at lease one place where I'm trying to use this library, the component is in a modal dialog that is used to login to the site.  Below is the html template code for the component:

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true" (click)="hideModal()">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center"> Login to Rove </h3>
    </div>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group login-username">
                <div>
                    <input name="log" id="login-user" class="form-control input" size="20"
                            [(ngModel)]="model.email" placeholder="Enter User Email" type="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group login-password">
                <div>
                    <input name="Password" id="login-password" class="form-control input" size="20"
                            [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="checkbox login-remember">
                        <input name="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" 
                                [(ngModel)]="model.rememberMe" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input name="submit" class="btn  btn-block btn-lg btn-primary" value="LOGIN" type="submit">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p class="text-center">
            Not here before? <a data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal"
                                href="#ModalSignup">Sign Up.</a> <br>
            <a href="forgot-password.html"> Lost your password? </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

The code above is without the icheck-bootstrap implemented code.  Below I have changed the key lines of code that will implement the checkbox as per the readme documention on the github site

```
    <div class="icheck-success checkbox login-remember">
        <input id="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" 
                [(ngModel)]="model.rememberMe" type="checkbox">
        <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label>
    </div>
```

this code works as per the readme, unfortunately, after the dialog has been closed the modality of the modal dialog stays and the main page behind it will not allow any input from keyboard or mouse.

Note the input tag in the effective lines, I have change from the name attribute, to the id attribute.  That seems wrong to me but, it is as the documentation suggests and, the only way it will completely work.  If I do not change the attribute from name to id the checkbox changes to the correct style but it will not check to show a true state. In fact if I remove the icheck-success class from the class attribute of the above div line the behavior is identical and the component will still not take input after the dialog box has been closed if I use the id attribute instead of the name attribute.

I'm using Angular V9 and the dialog component that I am using is from the Valor Software ngx-bootstrap library and, as stated, it works perfectly when I code the html input tag with the name attribute.  Does any know of a workaround or possibly what is happening here? the styling is what I want on the site but not at the cost of not having the login dialog effectively lock the site up after you login.

Thanks for any info that you may have on this issue.

Comment: can u create a minimal app with https://stackblitz.com/? more easy for people help u debug on it

Comment: @HanJeaHwan, Will try, I haven't done one yet (a stackblitz) but, I will give it a try, it'll be a good exercise anyway so I fully see it unshrouded... Working on it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix the problem I was having.  The first part of the problem was that I was not asking the right question.  I have edited the question to ask it in a better way, I think.

I have fixed the problem with the html below:

```
    <div class="icheck-success checkbox login-remember">
        <input id="rememberme" name="rememberme" [(ngModel)]="model.rememberMe" type="checkbox">
        <label for="rememberme">Remember Me</label>
    </div>
```

it seems I had to have a name attribute in the input tag for some reason that I'm not clear about at all but, this is what I did to get the modal dialog to truly clear from the page after close.

Comment: Input elements require a `name` attribute to be considered a [successful control](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) - without that attribute, the value won't be included in the form when submitted. The label's `for` attribute points to the `id` attribute, so you basically need both.

Comment: Another alternative is to include the checkbox within the label after the text.  They are then linked.